# Fix a merge that didn't include any changes?

Tags: git, merge

Our team just realized that some changes we made a couple days ago are missing. I believe it's possible that one of our merge commits didn't include any of the changes that it should have.

Here is what I see in SourceTree[image: SourceTree]

The highlighted commit is the merge which SourceTree says doesn't have any file changes. Changes in cd50.. and other commits since that one are missing (though not all of them). My theory is that the highlighted merge didn't change anything, but added the changes to the history and prevented them from being added properly in subsequent merges.

If this is correct, how can we get all the changes merged back properly?

Comment: Matt, you might be mistaken. Green came from yellow and the second purple came from green.

Comment: Ah, it appears I was mistaken.

Comment: That comment looks like an excerpt from the color Bible now